# Screen should move up without disturbing footer when keyboard appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing mobile app. I am using HTML, CSS, bootstrap, JavaScript for development. When the user taps on the textbox inside the footer, the keyboard pops up, screen is not moving up for android phones, but for ios it is working fine. I am trying to scroll down to the bottom div when the user taps on the textbox.

```
<body onload="hidebtn()">
   <header class="topBar">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs row" id="myTab" role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item col">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="chat()">Chat</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item col">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="ticketStatus()">Incident</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item col">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="ticketStatus()">Service Request</a>
         </li>
      </ul>     
      </header>
     <br><br>
     <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row h-100">
                 <div id="topButtons" class="card-body" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 12px; height: 80px;"></div>
                 <div id="chatBody" class="card-body anyClass">
                    <p class="WC_message_fl"><img class="con_im" src="images\chatrobo.png"></p>
                    <p class="WC_message_fl sahlaIntro"> Type your Questions & Start chatting</p>
                    </br></br>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" >
              </br></br>
              <p class="WC_message_fl" id='msg_table'></p>
              <div class="container" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;height:84vh;"><div class="row"  id="table"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab" >
           </br></br>
           <p class="WC_message_fl" id='msg_sr_table'></p>
           <div class="container" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;height:84vh;"><div class="row" id="sr_table"></div></div>
            </div>
         </div>     

         <footer id="footerChtbt" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;line-height: 20px;background-color: #ECEFF1;font-size: 0.6rem;border-top: 1px solid #aaa;box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 #9B9B9B;">
           <span id="sahlaResp" style="color:blue; position: relative;left: 7vw;top:0;"></span>
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-10">
                    <input id="query" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = 'Ask Sahla bot...'" onkeyup="pressedkey(event)" onClick="clickedQuery()" style="outline:0;box-shadow:none;font-size:14px;" required/>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-2" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 2px;">
                    <img src="images/send_icon.svg" name="submitbtn" onClick="sendbtn()" style="cursor: pointer; width: 38px;">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </footer>
```

I am trying to scroll down to the div on click of textbox

```
function clickedQuery() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#chatBody").scrollTop($("#chatBody")[0].scrollHeight); }, 100);
};
```

Comment: Few questions for you @PriyamMishra:
1) What kind of app is it? Hybrid or web app?

2) If hybrid, are you using a framework or similar to generate the apk with a webview? Which one?

3) What does "works fine" means for you? With "moving up" you mean that the browser window does not resize and keyboard overlaps the interface?

Comment: @DanielAbril It's web app.Yes keyboard is overlapping the interface. Whole screen should move up whenever keyboard appears.

Comment: OK @PriyamMishra, then you must know that the keyboard behaviour depends on the browser. You don't have control over it. When you build a native app you can set the keyboard mode. But in this case, the browser is the app, so you have to be creative to solve this kind of issues. This evening I'll answer with a solution that I use in this cases. Put some CSS for me in your question, please. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: @DanielAbril I have used inline style

Comment: Sorry, yesterday I didn't have time at the end. I'll try this evening @PriyamMishra

Comment: Having been through this exact same problem and spending weeks trying to build a solution: NOPE. CAN'T BE DONE. You need to go with a hybrid or native approach that gives you direct control over the keyboard.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was trying to explain.  Only native apps (such as the browser) have access to that device feature, and determine one or another behaviour of the keyboard. However, unless you fix some part of your content, the browser is going to let you scroll your content from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I've been checking your code, that sincerely you could have cleaned a bit for us... **You should send us a link were we can properly check the problem.** However I'll try to guide you with the little info I have.

In my experience, browsers resize when the keyboard opens on mobile. The content "overlapped" by the keyboard is accessible scrolling down. The real overlap happens on apps that has set the option to not resize when opening the keyboard. In that case, you never put inputs that can be overlapped, or if you do, you can make them position over the top line of the keyboard when receive the focus.

To do that you normally use `position: fixed` to position your input just on top of the bottom line of the viewport which should match the top line of the keyboard.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}
footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #ccc;
}
input {
  margin: 6px;
}
input:focus {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <input id="input" type="text">
</footer>
```

But as you report that your content is being overlapped maybe there is something else that I can't check without an online version of your code. So another solution is to use JS to relocate your whole footer. Then you can style it as you will to make it look nicer.

Aside of that. I recommend you add a button that blurs the input field in case the users doesn't finally want to summit. That will close the keyboard.[Something like this](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/hide-keyboard-button_60759)

Hope this solves your issue.

```js
$('#input').on('focus', function(){
$(this).parent('footer').css('bottom', '50%');
});
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}
footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 6px;
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <input id="input" type="text">
</footer>
```